# Go syscall call windows

Tags: go, system-calls

Im currently trying to use user32.dll EnumWindows on Go but seems to not be working

```
var(
    user32 = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    procEnumWindows = user32.NewProc("EnumWindows")
)

func EnumWindows() int {
    ret, _, _ := procEnumWindows.Call(
        syscall.NewCallback(enumWindowsProc),
        uintptr(0),
    )
    return int(ret)
}

func enumWindowsProc(hwnd syscall.Handle, lparam uintptr) bool {
    return true
}
```

Calling EnumWindows will give the following error:

```
panic: compileCallback: output parameter size is wrong
```

Im not sure how should I use the syscall package... I cant seem to find enough documentation on it

On the MSDN doc page it says that the callback should return a BOOL and thats what I am doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BOOL` in WinAPI is declared as `typedef int BOOL`. So it doesn't match Go's `bool`. Specifications doesn't even mention what's the size it has. It's probably 1 byte but it doesn't say it. You should use `int32` instead.

Comment: I think the specification does this on purpose: specifically to prevent abuses such as making C code write something to a Go value of type `bool` and then expect the Go code to interpret it "the right way".  All-in-all, you can know the size of a boolean value at runtime via [`unsafe.Sizeof()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Sizeof).